# Slide out vertically submenu on click

Tags: javascript, html, menu

Example:
http://kettlenyc.com/

The example above is exactly what I'd like to achieve: I'd like for there to be a submenu/div that slides out vertically onclick of the original links.. how can I do that? 
Notice how the part that slides out comes out 100% horizontally? Another similar example is: http://pollenlondon.com/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use a javascript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) which has prebuilt effects for creating those kinds of slide animations. I'd advice you to look specifically at the [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) effects, although special consideration must be taken about how the library modifies particular css values of the elements you wish to animate and how it affects the rest of the html.

If you provide a sample of your markup, further assitance could be offered.

Hope this helps.